# How to give bottom border radius only in flexiblespace of SliverAppBar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliverappbar

I want to have a  `sliverAppBar` with a rounded bottom border like this.

[image]

But it shouldn't be rounded when collapsed. Like this.

[image]

I tried a lot of solutions, but couldn't find anything.

```
SliverAppBar(
      leading: BackButton(color: Colors.black),
      pinned: true,
      snap: false,
      floating: false,
      expandedHeight: 250,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffEBEBEB),
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red,               
                fontSize: 16.0,
              )),
         
          background: FlutterLogo()),
    ),
   
    SliverList(...)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to wrap your FlutterLogo() by a Container with a border radius?

Comment: Hi, Yes I tried that but it didn't work.